# Importing a MySQL database from Live site to localhost - (wamp or xampp) gives errors

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I have installed wordpress on my webserver, but I want to export the database to my localhost until I finish the site, then upload the database to the server.

I tries exporting through phpmyadmin but when importing it into my localhost phpmyadmin (on wamp) it give some errors.

Is this possible or there is easier options.

Comment: What errors does it give you????

Comment: Are you using WampServer or XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Check your phpmyadmin can import to a large size, if it cannot, amend your php.ini upload sizings

> upload_max_filesize = 10M

Also you can upload a .sql as a .zip through phpmyadmin.

Also check your database exists that you need to upload the file into. Without you actually stating the issue there isn't much more to go on.